# Keep input content in modal when close and open modal with another controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a service for modal.

```
'use strict';

 var contactService = function ($modal) {

 return {

  openModal: function() {
   var modalInstance = $modal.open({
     animation: false,
     templateUrl: 'contact/views/contact.html',
     controller: require('../controllers/contact.controller'),
     controllerAs: 'ct',
     windowClass: 'modal-info contact',
    });
  }
 };
};

contactService.$inject = ['$modal'];

module.exports = contactService;
```

And I open this modal at some link. When I open, input some text in modal contact us and close it. At another controller I reopen this modal, when modal open, I want to some text is keep. It mean this modal just render only one time.
Help me about it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the "services". "Service" are function that you can inject inside controller like modules, so when you close or reopen the modal you'll set the variable inside the directive and you'll have your variable allready set.

Update
rapid example

a Service

```
var service=angular.module('serviceCtrl',[]);

service.controller('serviceCtrl',function($scope,$modalInstance,$http){
    this.something;
}
```

a controller with service injected

```
var homeController=angular.module('homeController',['ui.bootstrap','ui.utils','serviceCtrl']);
 homeController.controller('menuCtrl',function($scope,$http,$state,serviceCtrl){
serviceCtrl.something=somethingelse;
}
```

Comment: I want to call this modal one time and not store data with controller or service

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand well, you open a modal, from some state with some link, now you go to another state, you want to reopen that modal and you want to re-render it with the same values assiociate/written befor, am i wrong?